# Xcode How can I get a list of all misspelled words in a code?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have enabled Spelling and Grammar feature in Xcode and it works fine for a current document. Now, I would like to show all warnings in Issue Navigator. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Check Spelling and Grammar feature only works once you have a document selected. There is no such feature to scan the whole XCode project and list all warning in Issue navigator